# Подскажите алгоритм кластеризации

Tags: python, алгоритм, c++, кластеризация, mysql

Проблема в следующем. Есть БД с, примерно, 50млрд unsigned bigint строками. Для дальнейшей работы с ними их нужно кластеризовать по условию заданного расстояния Хэмминга (т.е. заранее количество кластеров неизвестно). И, естественно, никакой оперативки не хватит, что обработать этот объем за раз. Соответственно, алгоритм должен быть инкрементальным, с поступательным добавлением новых данных.
Собственно, вопрос: есть ли такой алгоритм в природе? Желательно, реализованный на каком-нибудь распространенном языке (потому что чисто математику я не пойму). На вскикду, загуглить не удалось :/

Задача не гипотетическая, проект коммерческий :)
Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Вторая ссылка в гугле: [Подсчет расстояния Хэмминга на большом наборе данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211264/)

Comment: Конечно, я видел этот пост). HEngine не подходит - он весь объем хранит в оперативке - уже на 50млн сервер падает. Если же переписывать под sql, то, во-первых, теряется вся скорость, во-вторых, нет возможности сортировки и бинарного поиска. Поэтому отпадает :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так если это расстояние между числами будет равно 1, то весь набор данных в один кластер запихать?

Или другая ситуация - сейчас у нас две записи, расстояние между ними равно 2. Распихали их по двум кластерам. Завтра появилась запись, у которой расстояние с первой и второй записью равно 1 - куда ее пихать? Или кластеры надо объединять?

Первое легко может быть, если все числа идут по порядку. А из этого вытекает уже и второе.

Comment: Это не я )

Товарищи доброжелатели! Я когда захочу ответить - я и сам могу ответить ) А пока я задачу хотел уточнить - поэтому комментарием сделал. Тем более, что ответ @Yura Ivanov, куда больше на ответ похож

Comment: Это, полагаю, можно решить частично рандомным расставлением центроидов и более менее равномерным распределением в кластерах (т.е. регулярно считать их размер). Кроме того, один кластер может содержать несколько хешей. Да и при таком объеме не страшен определенный процент ложных срабатываний.

Comment: @anagamin, ну если вас устраивает примерный алгоритм, то почему бы не придумать его самому? Тем более сомневаюсь, что для таких целей распространены по инету примерные алгоритмы. Скорее всего используются точные, а точные, как мы выяснили, вам не подходят.

Один из "примерных" - пойти от обратного. Выбрать количество кластеров, для каждого из них выбрать "стандартные" значения. Для каждой записи определяем принадлежность к тому или иному кластеру (или используем тот, до которого расстояние минимально) - т.к. "дефолтные" значения заданы, то время будет линейным.

Comment: @anagamin, либо еще вариант:

Берем первую запись, строим все возможные узлы из нее (т.е. значения, расстояние до которых не более исходного). Для каждого такого узла (который к тому же есть в исходном наборе) находим следующих соседей и т.д. до некоторой степени вложенности. Помещаем все записи в кластер.

Далее берем следующую необработанную запись, проводим те же шаги и помещаем в следующий кластер и т.д.

Т.к. вычисления ограничиваем некоторым числом погружений - не все нужные записи попадут в один кластер, но вам это и не надо. Если немного оптимизировать - то с памятью проблем не будет.

Comment: Да, похоже, это - единственное решение. Я просто надеялся, что гений математики сможет обойти линейную сложность и на порядки увеличит итоговую скорость процесса. Похоже, увы :)